# Show that $[0, \infty)$ fails the Heine-Borel property.

Tags: real-analysis, covering-spaces

I would like to thank @C Squared for helping me out with open covers. I have updated this page with a correct answer.

I want to show $[0, \infty)$ fails the Heine-Borel property. With some help, I was able to come up with a method of proof so I want to know if I got it right on this one. Any corrections would be appreciated, thank you!

Observe that $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (-k, k)$ covers $[0, \infty)$ by letting $x\in [0, \infty)$. It follows by definition of the set that,

\begin{equation*}
0 \leq x,
\end{equation*}
By the archimedean property, it follows that there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that,

\begin{equation*}
-k < 0 \leq x < k
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x \in\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (-k, k)
\end{equation*}
so,
\begin{equation*}
[0, \infty) \subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (-k, k).
\end{equation*}

Now observe that $\bigcup_{k=1}^n (-k, k)$ does not cover $[0, \infty)$ because $k+1\in[0,\infty)$ but $k+1\not\in\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (-k, k)$-by the definition of the set.

\begin{equation*}
[0, \infty) \not\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n (-k, k)
\end{equation*}

Therefore $[0, \infty)$ fails the Heine-Borel property and is not compact.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is not an open subset of $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: What is the Heine-Borel property?

Comment: @Ramanujan and OP, What you are showing is that $[0,\infty)$ is not compact by direct proof and you are not making use of the Heine-Borel theorem. The Hiene-Borel theorem states that in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. The set $[0,\infty)$ is closed because its complement is open, however it is not bounded, so it is not compact.

Comment: @Ramanujan If for every open cover of $A$ there exists a finite subcover that covers $A$, then $A$ satisfies the Heine-Borel property. So I need to show that there exists an open cover such that all of its subcovers do not cover $A$. I think I understand now... $[0, \infty)$ covers itself but it isn't open...

Comment: also, your "open cover" is not an open cover because $\{0\}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ or $[0,\infty)$. Try modifying it with an open ball centered at $0$.

Comment: no, it depends on what topology you are working in. If you are working in the subspace topology inherited by $[0,\infty)$, then $[0,\infty)$ is open

Comment: @C Squared Let's just assume I'm in Analysis I.

Comment: what is that supposed to mean? Analysis $I$ is completely ambiguous and non-standard throughout the world

Comment: @C Sqaured thank you! I got the idea down. I was so focused on covering the set I forgot it had to be open. Just got to this today.

Comment: You are confusing the Heine-Borel property with the definition of compact.  They are not the same.  The definition of "compact" applies to sets in a topological space (compact: If every open cover of a set X must contain a finite subcover then $X$ is compact). They Heine-Borel property refers to the *space* itself. A space has the Heine-Borel property if a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.  $\mathbb R$ has the Heine-Borel property and every question you've asked *passes* the HB property *BECAUSE* the sets are not closed on bounded and are not compact.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken.  As a space $(0,1)$ does not have the HB property because the HB theroem is not true.  Namely $(0,1)$ is *closed* (it's the entire space) and bounded ($d(x,y) < 1$ for all $x,y\in (0,1)$ but not compact.

Comment: @fleablood you're not using first principles. " A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the Heine-Borel property if for every open cover $C$ of $A$,
there exists a finite subcover $C'$ of $C$ still covering $A$".

Comment: @fleablood I am not allowed to use any theorem.

Comment: Hmm..... what text are you using?  If that *is* what your class and text says, then you are have done both these questions correctly.  But I've never seen a text use the term "Heine-Borel property" that way (which is just a synonym for compact).  You are correct that that is why $[0,\infty)$ is not compact (boils down to not being bounded) but I would refer to that as "the Heine-Borel Property".

Comment: I'm not saying you *use* the Heine-Borel Theorem.  I am saying the Heine-Borel Property means the theorem is true.  In other words, according to *my* textbooks a space has the Heine-Borel Property if a set in the space is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for contradiction, that $[0,\infty)$ was compact. Then by the Heine-Borel theorem, $[0,\infty)$ is closed and bounded. However, we know that $[0,\infty)$ is not bounded, therefore we have reached a contradiction. Our assumption that $[0,\infty)$ was compact must be false.

Comment: @C Squared. Yea I saw that but my professor wants me to use the definition of the Heine-Borel property. I fixed the proof, how's that?

Comment: @xhsbm its better now, but for the last line, your top index should be $n$, not $\infty$ on the arbitrary union

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the question.  The Heine-Borel property doesn't refer to $[0,\infty)$ being compact.  The Heine-Borel property refers to considering $[0, \infty)$ as a metric space and seeing if the Heine-Borel property is true in the space.

And $[0,\infty)$ *has* the Heine-Borel property because the Heine-Borel theorem is true on $[0,\infty)$.  A subset $X \subset [0,\infty)$ is compact if and only if $X$ is closed and bounded.

But $(0,\infty)$ *fails* the Heine-Borel property because the Heine-Borel theorem is *not* true on $(0,\infty)$.  The subset $(0,1]$ is not compact ($\{(\frac 1n, 2)\}$ is an open cover with not finite subcover) but $(0,1]$ *is* closed and bounded.  That is, it is closed in $(0, \infty)$ (but not in $\mathbb R$ or even in $[0,\infty)$.

It is closed because it contains all its limit points because $0$ does not exist in the space $(0, \infty)$ and is not a limit point.